# Apache Tika Api consuming given stream

Tags: apache, stream, mime-types, apache-tika

I use Apache Tika bundle dependency for a Project to find out MimeTypes for Files. due to some issues we have to find out through InputStream. it is actually guaranteed to mark / reset given InputStream. Tika-Bundle includes core and parser api and uses PoifscontainerDetector , ZipContainerDetector, OggDetector, MimeTypes and Magic for detection. I have been debugging for 3 hours and all of Detectors mark and reset after detection. I did it in following way.

```
  TikaInputStream tis = null;
    try {
        TikaConfig config = new TikaConfig();
        tikaDetector = config.getDetector();
        tis =  TikaInputStream.get(in);
        MediaType mediaType = tikaDetector.detect(tis, new Metadata());

        if (mediaType != null) {
            String[] types = mediaType.toString().split(",");

            for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
                mimeTypes.add(new MimeType(types[i]));
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Mime Type for given Stream could not be resolved: ", e);
    }
```

But Stream is consumed. Does anyone know how to find out MimeTypes without consuming Stream?

Comment: I don't see you marking or resetting the TikaInputStream in your code, could it be as simple as that?

Comment: actually yes. detect method of Detectors is expected to do mark and reset. I debugged so many times and saw that all Detectors mark and reset the given Stream. Why should I mark and reset inputstream? and I also tried to set mark to 0 and reset after getting MediaType. But Stream was consumed :(

Comment: all we should do is give a markSupported inputstream like BufferedInputStream. if I give an Inputstream for pdf files, stream is not consumed but it doesnt work for streams for xlsx formats. I think its due to read whole stream for zip detection. and there isnt any way to detect xlsx format without consuming stream. :(

Answer (score 6):

This problem bugged me for a while too before I finally solved it.  The problem is that, while Detector.detect() methods are required to mark and reset the stream, this resetting will have no effect on your original stream (the `in` variable) if marking is not supported in that stream.

In order to get this to work, I had to first convert my stream to a `BufferedInputStream` before doing anything else.  I would then pass that buffered stream to the detect algorithm, and I would use that same buffered stream later for parsing, reading, or whatever I needed to do.

```
BufferedInputStream buffStream = new BufferedInputStream(in);
TikaInputStream tis = null;
try {
    TikaConfig config = new TikaConfig();
    tikaDetector = config.getDetector();
    tis =  TikaInputStream.get(buffStream);
    MediaType mediaType = tikaDetector.detect(tis, new Metadata());

    if (mediaType != null) {
        String[] types = mediaType.toString().split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
            mimeTypes.add(new MimeType(types[i]));
        }
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Mime Type for given Stream could not be resolved: ", e);
} 

// further along in my code...

doSomething(buffStream); // rather than doSomething(in)
```

Comment: Given that a TikaInputStream is already buffering, can you not just use a TikaInputStream for everything, and avoid the extra wrapper?

Comment: @Gagravarr - Absolutely.  The only catch is that you then have to pass the TikaInputStream into doSomething(), not the original InputStream.  In my own code, I used BufferedInputStream because I wanted something a bit more generic/not associated with Tika.